# books or articles on methodically analyzing hand history

Tags: hand-history, books

Are there any books out there that teaches you how to methodically go through you own hand history? looking less for theory, more on something that is more practical and instructive and maybe some examples on how top players go through their hand history. I'm sure that many of them have probably developed a routine to address this issue. I'm looking for training tips on how to analyze your own hand history.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question. I've seen this one in other sites as well, instead of books they only recommend to study your opponents stats. Never seen a book for this topic, but for an article you just have to read [this](http://archives1.twoplustwo.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=8629906&page=0&fpart=all&vc=1).

Comment: Not a book but a poker camp

Comment: I also liked Gus Hansen's "Every Hand Revealed"

Comment: James "Splitsuit" Sweeney has a few hand reading books.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are looking for Phil Gordon's little Green, Blue, and Gold books.
I'll make no claim, but do consider some material in some books is perhaps 'dated.'

Comment: I believe Gordon's books are Green, Blue and **Black**

Comment: I guess when buying a set of 3, you are correct. 
But, for sure there is a gold book.
http://www.amazon.com/Phil-Gordons-Little-Gold-Book/dp/1451641591

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to read "Polished poker" by John Anhalt 
You can also try to use different analyzing software like leak buster or ace poker drills. It helps you to analyze your game and improve your gaming skills.

Comment: i can't seem to find this book on amazon.

Comment: @jason There is more than Amazon in this world

Answer (score 0):

I thought that Ed Miller's analysis in "The Poker 1%" is excellent and a great model for using on your own.

Answer (score 0):

For practicality, there's ***Every Hand Revealed*** by Gus Hansen, where he goes over his thought process during the 2007 Aussie Millions, and the 3 volume set, ***Winning Poker Tournaments One Hand at a Time***, by Eric Lynch, Jon Turner, Jon Van Fleet, and Matthew Hilger.